# passing mongo doc id via param to angular directive function throws parse error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```js
var app = angular.module('my-app', [], function () {

});

app.controller('AppController', function () {
});

app.directive('copyMe', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    replace:true,
    scope:{wid:'='},
    template: '<div ng-click="copy()">Copy me</div>',
    link: function compile(scope, element, attrs ) {
      scope.copy = function(){
        alert( attrs.wid );
      };
    } 
   };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/angular/bower-angular/master/angular.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

</head>

 <body ng-app="my-app" ng-controller="AppController">
  <copy-me wid="'1dfvdfv23'"></copy-me>
  <copy-me wid="2"></copy-me>
  <copy-me wid="3"></copy-me>
 </body>  
  
</html>
```

A simple ang directive. I need to re-use the copy-me function in many places within my ang app. The problem is, the real world application of this is that the 'wid' is actually a mongo doc id which is a combination of letters and numbers.

For some reason, when I pass the mongo id in as the 'wid' angular throws a parse error.

When i passed the id in wrapped in single quotes it doesn't throw a parse error but does include the single quotes in the string.

Click on the different texts to see when you run the snippet. I know I can strip out the single quotes but that seems wrong.

Is there an official way to pass a multi char string via a directive in this way?

There is also a jsfiddle link: https://jsbin.com/bajulepewi/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

The scope wid attribute should be @, not =. = means bidirectional databinding (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#directive-definition-object), so the value you put on the attribute should be a property name on the scope or controller that ng will read from and write to. You get a parse error with your first example as that is not a valid property name, while the other two are valid. If you remove the first character of the first value, it should "work". However, your questions suggests you really want to use @ (one way binding), since you probably don't want to change the mongo doc ID within your directive.